Anyone else use this easy way to solve 'Tor does not have permission to access the profile'?
I was getting a "Tor does not have permission to access the profile. Please adjust your file system permissions and try again." Because i install my apps mostly on a secondary internal ssd drive, so when i have to reset windows for example, my apps all still work except a few and do not get removed on a reset. So, how to solve it ? the same way i solved chrome portable not opening from that location;
Right click and 'open as administrator'
done. No need to start digging deeper

Please post the question and answer separately, otherwise your post makes no sense as a question.
